# Include multiple composer repository configuration files

Tags: php, composer-php

I want to break up the composer repository configuration into different files.

I use local and external repositories and I would like to keep their configurations separate.

These files would then be pulled into the main composer.json when running the install or update task.

Is this possible?

Comment: Some added background: The reason why I want to break up the configuration like this is to allow one of these files to be under svn-ignore. I have a script that will create a blank .json file in place of the ignored file when I checkout the project.

Comment: Are you saying you want split your composer.json into two (or more) files and then have these files smartly joined together to be used when running `./composer.phar install` or `./composer.phar update`?

Comment: Yes, that's what im after. Two or more files which are joined together when an install or an update is ran

Answer (score 5, accepted):

There is now a plugin called [composer-merge-plugin](https://github.com/wikimedia/composer-merge-plugin) which can merge multiple composer files at runtime.

### Usage:

Assume you have your main `composer.json` file located in a base path, and then you have other `composer.json` files that you'd like to load from subdirectories in `/plugins`:

```
/
|-- composer.json
|-- /plugins
    |-- /kittenizer
        |-- composer.json
    |-- /puppyizer
        |-- composer.json
```

In your main `composer.json` file, you can load these with:

```
{
    "require": {
        "wikimedia/composer-merge-plugin": "~1"
    },
    "extra": {
        "merge-plugin": {
            "include": [
                "plugins/*/composer.json"
            ],
            "recurse": true,
            "replace": false,
            "merge-dev": true,
            "merge-extra": false
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Simple and with an easy usage, cool!

Answer (score 3):

I'm quite late to the party, but I had a similar issue and solved it without a composer plugin.

```
/root
|-- composer.json
|-- /vendor
|-- /more-dependencies
    |-- composer.json
```

Your composer file in the root-dir:

```json
{
    "repositories": [
        {
            "type": "path",
            "url": "more-dependencies"
        }
    ],
    "require": {
        "something/more-dependencies": "dev-master"
    }
}
```

Your composer file in your other directory (`more-dependencies`) has to contain at least the following:

```json
{
    "name": "something/more-dependencies"
}
```

You can now `composer install` in your root directory and anything specified in your subfolder's `composer.json` will land in your root's vendor folder.

❗ Warning: Only root's composer.json can include repository metadata, not the one in the subfolder ([composer-doc](https://getcomposer.org/doc/04-schema.md#repositories)).

Side note: In my case the composer.json in the subdir is a cloneable resource. I use the composer hook [pre-install-cmd](https://getcomposer.org/doc/articles/scripts.md#:%7E:text=pre-install-cmd) to make sure "more-dependencies" are existing and up-to-date.

```json
"scripts": {
    "more-dependencies": [
        "git -C more-dependencies pull || git clone https://example/more-dependencies.git more-dependencies"
    ],
    "pre-install-cmd": [ "@more-dependencies" ],
    "pre-update-cmd": [ "@more-dependencies" ]
},
```

Comment: First... thanks for taking the time to offer up a solution without wikimedia/composer-merge-plugin. Can you be more specific about how you are using pre-install-cmd to make sure "more-dependencies" are existing and up-to-date?

Comment: @kreynen I updated my explanation to (hopefully) answer your question.